# R squared formula in linear regression

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

Hi I'm trying to find the value of $R^2$ but I think that I'm missing something.
I've been given the values of the following sums: $$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \sum_{i=1}^n y_i\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i$$
Where $x_i$ is the independent variable and $y_i$ the dependent variable of mi linear model.

I'm supossed to find the value of the determination coefficient $R^2$. I've try with several formulas of it but I always miss something I think that I need $\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i$ but I'm not sure.

I have this formulas for $R^2$

$R^2=\hat{\beta}^2\frac{\sum(x_i-\bar{x})^2}{\sum(y_i-\bar{y})^2}$

$R^2=\frac{\sum(\hat{y}_i-\bar{y})^2}{\sum(y_i-\bar{y})^2}$

$R^2=\frac{(\sum(y_i-\bar{y})(x_i-\bar{x}))^2}{\sum(y_i-\bar{y})^2\sum(x_i-\bar{x})^2}$

The model is $y_i=\hat{\alpha}+\hat{\beta}x_i+e_i$ Where $e_i$ is an error of mean 0

If someone can help me I'll be very grateful. Thanks!

Comment: How about showing us one of the 'several' formulas you tried, and the computation you made from it? That would help us match the level and content of your background in regression or the course you are taking.

Comment: You have $\sum_i y_i,$ but $\sum_i(y_i-\bar y)^2 = \sum_i y_i^2 - n\bar y^2,$ so it seems it's $\sum y_i^2$ that you're missing.